# Creating another full page for Chrome extension (React+Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome

I am using React + TypeScript

I want to create a **full page** for my chrome extension.

My webconfig looks like this:

```json
entry: {
    popup: path.join(__dirname, "src/popup.tsx"),
    content: path.join(__dirname, "src/content.ts"),
    background: path.join(__dirname, "src/background.ts"),
    dashboard: path.join(__dirname, "src/frontend/dashboard.tsx"),
    login: path.join(__dirname, "src/frontend/login.tsx")
  }
```

Somehow everything will be included in my dashboard.js, even background.ts.
Of course I am not calling background.ts functions from dashboard.tsx.
How can I prevent it? There are "sensitive" requests in background.ts and I dont want to show to user everything on the frontend  so easily.